# Different order for columns in Unique Index and Primary Key

Tags: index, order-by

I have Index `Index1` as `(col1,col2)` and I have `PK Index1(col2,col1)`. Unique Index and Primary Key with same name, same columns but with different order of columns. In such case, how Primary Key is using that index?

Comment: Could you please provide DDL for creating "Unique Index and Prim Key with same name, same columns but with different order of columns"? That might help us to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Maybe you could also indicate what database system you are running (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, ...)?

Comment: Preferably also including its version. Thanks.

Comment: By DDL I mean the SQL commands that were (or could be) used to produce this issue (an index and the PK by the same name defined on the same table and on the same columns but with the columns listed in a different order). I can't imagine how this is possible to begin with, never mind the question you are asking. If you don't know how it was done, perhaps you could elaborate on where you are observing this? And again, please indicate the database product (and version thereof) that you are using.

Comment: Regardless how it was done, I doubt that the names (the index name and the PK name) matter at all in how the index and the PK are used. But in order to understand where you are confused, please provide the details requested. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server tables that have a clustered index, both the primary key and the clustered index, by default, use a common index structure.  However, you can easily specify a non-clustered primary key, along with a clustered index composed of different columns.

For example:

```
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.TestF', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.TestF;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Test', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Test;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    Col1 int NOT NULL
    , Col2 int NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT PK_Test
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
        (Col2, Col1)
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_Test
ON dbo.Test (Col1, Col2);
```

When the primary key and the clustered index for a table are not defined on the same columns (and with columns in the same order), two separate indexes are created. The clustered index, which is the table itself, and the non-clustered primary key index which gets automatically defined as "unique".

Inserting rows into the clustered index results in rows being inserted into the unique primary key:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (Col1, Col2)
SELECT o1.object_id, o2.object_id
FROM sys.objects o1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2;
```

[image]

As you can see from the above execution plan, inserting rows into the table requires a sort of the inserted values prior to them being inserted into the primary key index.  This extra sort and index insert mean you should have a very good reason for having a clustering key that is different from the primary key for the table.

If you attempt to insert non-unique values, the primary key insert will fail with "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint xxx. Cannot insert duplicate key in object xxx".

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 45
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Test'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Test'. The duplicate key value is (-1578609445, -1578609445).

Referential Integrity will perform a seek into the primary key index on the referenced table, without needing to scan the clustered index.  As an example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestF
(
    Col1 int NOT NULL
    , Col2 int NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT FK_TestF_Test
        FOREIGN KEY (Col2, Col1)
        REFERENCES dbo.Test(Col2, Col1)
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE INDEX IX_TestF
ON dbo.TestF (Col2, Col1);
```

Insert some data into the referencing table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestF (Col1, Col2)
VALUES (27, 42);
```

As you can see in the execution plan below, there is a seek into the primary key to ensure referential integrity is maintained.

[image]

Of note, you could create the table without a clustered index, using just a primary key index.  For certain implementations, such as loading data into a staging area, this can be far more optimal.  Our example table, `dbo.Test` above can be made into a heap table, i.e. one not using a clustered index, by simply not defining the clustered index:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    Col1 int NOT NULL
    , Col2 int NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT PK_Test
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
        (Col2, Col1)
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Be aware that the space occupied by rows deleted from a heap is not automatically re-used by SQL Server.  To regain that unused space for future use, you need to either `ALTER TABLE dbo.Test REBUILD` or, if deleting all the rows in the table is desirable, and there is no  referential integrity pointing at the table, `TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Test`.